# Value Error when fitting data with statsmodel OLS method

Tags: python, machine-learning, statsmodels, valueerror, spatial-regression

I am trying to fit my data with the stats model OLS method. While following from a tutorial, imported all the necessary libraries;

```
from scipy import stats
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import numpy
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

Then defined all the variable names from the X_train data;

```
variable_names = [
 'Block', 
 'Acreage', 
'dist_Kyanuuna_TC', 
'dist_Busunju_TC', 
'dist_Namungo_TC', 
'dist_Kitalya_TC',
'dist_Kabindula_TC', 
'dist_Namayumba_HC', 
'dist_BlueStarJr_Sch', 
'dist_Kyanuuna_HS',
'dist_Busunju_Col',
'Central_P',
'years',
'Use_Agric_Farm',
'Use_Res',
'Use_Res_Agric']
```

Then included the neighborhood variable to the formular, for which binary dummy varaibles are to be created and fitted without an intercept.

```
f = 'Value ~ ' + ' + '.join(variable_names) + ' + neighborhood - 1'
```

And finally fitted the data as below;

```
model2 = sm.OLS(f, data=X_train).fit()
print(m3.summary2())
```

However, this raises the;

```
ValueError: unrecognized data structures: <class 'str'> / <class 'NoneType'>
```

But I have failed to figure out what could be the issue. Any clues on how to approach this would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the document [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.formula.api.ols.html), it is `ols` instead of `OLS`

**Update:**
In your import section, you use both `sm` for two different packages. Removing the first one should work.

Comment: Well, i had used ols initially and raised the error "AttributeError: module 'statsmodels.api' has no attribute 'ols" So i changed it to OLS.

Comment: Which version of  `statsmodels` are you using?

Comment: lowercase models like `ols` are in statsmodesl.formula.api. or use `OLS.from_formula` method. (convention is to use `smf` as abbreviation for formula.api